# Flask: New request is killing the existing request

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, flask, wsgi

I have a python flask app running, It takes input in the list format and processes each of the list item sequentially using a for loop.
sample code:

```
getitems= request.get_json()
for i in getitems:
  {perform some action on i}
```

Typically the input list list size is in range of thousands and it takes 20 minutes to complete the actions on all the items. However, in this 20 minute window if a new request is recieved, the flask system is ignoring the previous request and processing the new request. what is the solutions for this?

My initial idea was to maintain a list which will store the items received from all the requests and then process them individually.
code snippet:

```
listglobal = []
getitems= request.get_json()
listglobal =listglobal + getitems
for i in listglobal :
  {perform some action on i}
listglobal=[]
```

However this doesn't seem to work and it is still ignoring the old request after receiving the new request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You many want to explore [celery](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/celery/). Long running task are better processed asynchronously. You can have your route return the task_id and track if the processing was a success or failure. Check out the below blog for a detailed explanation.

https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask

PS: I didn't write the article, but I have used it in past to solve a similar problem :)